# How do I prevent DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader from automatically adding InflateColumn::DateTime in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using [Catalyst](http://catalyst.perl.org) and [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) to create my model in Catalyst like so:

```
script/myapp_create.pl model DB DBIC::Schema MyApp::Schema create=static overwrite_modifications=1 components=EncodedColumn dbi:mysql:mydb mydb pass
```

Unfortunately the loader automatically sets up `InflateColumn::DateTime` as a default component, which I do not want. I want the raw value from the database.

```
__PACKAGE__->load_components("InflateColumn::DateTime", "EncodedColumn");
```

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man, that is annoying. Looks like it's not possible to get what you want as it is.

`_build_loader_components` in [Catalyst::Helper::Model::DBIC::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aHelper%3a%3aModel%3a%3aDBIC%3a%3aSchema) adds it unless you have no namespaces and no resultset namespace. It pushes your extra `component=` list onto that.

```
my @components = $self->old_schema && (not $use_namespaces) ? ()
    : ('InflateColumn::DateTime');
```

So, options–

1. [File a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Catalyst-Model-DBIC-Schema).
2. Do it with [dbicdump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?dbicdump).

This should be what you wanted–

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib \
    -o components='["EncodedColumn"]' \
    -o use_namespaces=1 \
    -o overwrite_modifications=1 \
    MyApp::Schema dbi:mysql:foo user pass
```

And then just the plain model to wrap it–

```
script/myapp_create.pl model DB DBIC::Schema MyApp::Schema
```

Update: Took out `preserve_case` as your example didn’t use it and I’d like to mention for the sake of best practices that the password should not be in the model or the schema classes. It should be in config and if you’re using something that allows it, like mysql, it should be configured to be read from a privilege restricted DB specific configuration file.

Comment: Hi Ashley,that's what I was afraid of, found that bit of code the helper also but was not sure if there was a way around it. I'll go the dbicdump way. Just wrote a small perl helper that manually dumps the schema. Not too bad. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score -1):

I make so and it worked:

```
script/myapp_create.pl model DB DBIC::Schema MyApp::Schema \
    create=static components=TimeStamp dbi:SQLite:myapp.db \
    on_connect_do="PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" \
    overwrite_modifications=1
```